# setting conditions based on time passed

Tags: java, if-statement, time, while-loop

I'm making this piece of code where I need to perform functions based on how long time has passed.

So say for a random example I want to measure the the time in milliseconds up to 10 and while this is happening it prints hello. During this process if it reaches 6 seconds I want it to print out goodbye for say 2 seconds and then after that continue printing out hello for a further 2 seconds until it reaches 10.

I assume this will be done with `if` statements and `while`loops but haven't been able to do it successfully.

I've been using `currentTimeMillis()` and I'd prefer to use that option to measure the time but in general, how would I be able to do the above in that way? The example's kind of stupid but what I actually want to do is similar so the above will do.

Thanks guys.

EDIT: As requested, this is what I've tried for the above example

```
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - x < 10000)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - x == 6000)
        {
            System.out.println("goodbye");
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - x > 8000)
            {
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you publish what have you done so far ?

Comment: You can't depends whatever you will hit the exact target mark of `6000` etc.. You should use a range of options or use Thread.sleep in order to create a delay and then the result you want to produce in each condition.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too and it worked in the respect of showing the hello and goodbye but doesn't go back to hello again after the specified time if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just record a start time and then do each loop until the current time reaches that start time plus whatever threshold. Something like:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long tenSecondsFromStart = startTime + 10*1000;
long eightSecondsFromStart = startTime + 8*1000;
long sixSecondsFromStart = startTime + 6*1000;


while(System.currentTimeMillis() < sixSecondsFromStart){
   System.out.println("Hello");
}

while(System.currentTimeMillis() < eightSecondsFromStart){
   System.out.println("Goodbye");
}

while(System.currentTimeMillis() < tenSecondsFromStart){
   System.out.println("Hello again");
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good way of doing it. In order to make it a variable and thus go on for any amount of time I'd just replace the 10, 8 or 6 with a variable am I right?

Comment: @Steglas Sure. This was just an example. You can modify this approach to do anything for any amount of time.